# Access previously iterated element within array.map

Tags: javascript, arrays

In JavaScript, I have an array of objects with ids, names and some other properties I'm mapping over to create a new object with modified properties. One of the properties needs to have a value related to the last iterated element. I.e. its predecessor, like so:

```
let returnedArrOfObjs = [{id: 1, name: 'first', predecessor: 'none' },
{id: 2, name: 'second', predecessor:'first'}, 
{id: 3, name: 'third', predecessor: 'second'}]
```

Is there a way I can access the previously iterated element?

This doesn't work as prevObj doesn't mean anything, but just to give a flavour of what I'm trying to do:

```
array.map(obj => {
        let rObj = {};
        rObj.id = obj.id,
        rObj.name = obj.name,
        rObj.predecessor = prevObj ? prevObj.name : 'none'
        return rObj;
    })
```

Comment: Declare `prevObj ` outside `map`. Then you have it.

Comment: Please don't use this like that. Write readable code. That said, JS is awesome: `array.map(({ id, name }, i, a) => ({ id, name, predecessor: a[i - 1]?.name ?? "none" }))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.map()` has a second parameter → the current loop index. With that you can get the last element like so:

```js
let array = [{id: 1, name: 'first' },
{id: 2, name: 'second'}, 
{id: 3, name: 'third'}];


const result = array.map((obj, i) => { // add index in the function parameters
    let rObj = {};
    rObj.id = obj.id;
    rObj.name = obj.name;
    
    const prevObj = i != 0 ? array[i - 1] : null; // If current index != 0, get the prev object
    rObj.predecessor = prevObj ? prevObj.name : 'none'
    return rObj;
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @EdwardWatson no problem. glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Your solution only misses one part i.e second argument. `map()` has a second argument i.e `index`. What you can do is check if there is an element in the previous index. If yes then use its `name` else make it `none`

```js
let arrOfObjs = [{id: 1, name: 'first' },
{id: 2, name: 'second'}, 
{id: 3, name: 'third'}] 

let returnedArrOfObjs=arrOfObjs .map((obj,index)=>{
let rObj = {};
        rObj.id = obj.id,
        rObj.name = obj.name,
        rObj.predecessor = arrOfObjs [index-1] ?  arrOfObjs [index-1].name : 'none'
        return rObj;
})

console.log(returnedArrOfObjs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way I can think of is using `Array.reduce`. It lets you retain information that you pass to the following iteration via `return`. It may get more convoluted than other solutions.

```js
let returnedArrOfObjs = [{id: 1, name: 'first', predecessor: 'none' },
{id: 2, name: 'second', predecessor:'first'}, 
{id: 3, name: 'third', predecessor: 'second'}] 

const { result } = returnedArrOfObjs.reduce(({ prevObj, result }, obj) => {
    let rObj = {};
    rObj.id = obj.id,
    rObj.name = obj.name,
    rObj.predecessor = prevObj ? prevObj.name : 'none'

    result = [ ...result, rObj ]

    return { prevObj: rObj, result }
}, { result: [] })

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Array `map` can have a **third argument**, the array itself. You can take advantage of it to get the previus item:

```js
const result = array.map((obj, index, currentArray) => {
    let rObj = {};
    rObj.id = obj.id;
    rObj.name = obj.name;

    // Get the previus object it's not the
    // first iteration:
    const prevObj = index != 0 
        ? currentArray[index - 1] 
        : null; 

    rObj.predecessor = prevObj ? prevObj.name : "none";
    return rObj;
});
```